# Is javascript unit testing a good idea?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I've been wondering this for a while and what framework is the best. I was going to look at JSUnit, but it looks like it's not actively maintained anymore.

Anybody know the pros-cons of the active unit testing frameworks? I would love to benefit from some of your experience.

EDIT: JsUnit... Not JUnit

Comment: Of course it's a good idea. Except when it's a bad idea. Or a neutral idea. Or a good idea with some downsides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript unit testing is a must. Especially on the server.

JavaScript is a weakly typed dynamic language and it's easy to make mistakes, unit testing will allow you to have confidence about the stability of your source code.

Automated unit tests for the server allow you to re factor easily and automated unit tests for the client allow you to assert browser compliance after every change

As for unit testing frameworks I would recommend [vows-is](https://github.com/Raynos/vows-is) for node.js and [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit) for the client-side.

Eventually I will port vows-is to work nicely as a client-side unit testing framework but it's not ready for that yet.

Answer (score -6):

JUnit is for Java - Not Javascript. Javascript runs on the browser - and I cannot think of anyway of unit testing. Javascript is just to make web pages interactive.

If you want to test a web page you need something like Quick Test Pro - for example.

Comment: My bad... meant to write JsUnit...

Comment: I disagree with "Javascript is just to make web pages interactive." take a look at node.js and the various other javascript engines and you'll see that javascript has evolved well beyond the browser.

Comment: Sorry I had to downvote this as well, sounds like something you would hear years ago from people who didn't take the language seriously.

Comment: I take the language serious - I just think that its chief ability is to make a web page interactive and flexible. I think other languages are better tgab trying to make a web server out of it (etc).

Comment: _"I cannot think of anyway of unit testing"_ - Who says unit testing has to be automated? It's certainly _convenient_ if you can automate it, but you don't have to. The important thing is that you do it, not how you do it.